# Почему возвращает пустой список

Tags: python, парсер

Хочу спарсить почту с сайте, но скрипт почему то выдает пустой список
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

код

```
all_links = []

def get_links():
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        links = tree.xpath('//h2[@itemprop="name"]/a')
        for lnk in links:
            all_links.append('https://www.ua-region.info{}'.format(lnk.get('href')))
            print('https://www.ua-region.info{}'.format(lnk.get('href')))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for url in all_pages:
    get_links()
print('{} links found'.format(len(all_links)))

mails = []

**def get_mail():
    try:
        mail = [i.text.encode('utf-8') for i in tree.xpath('//td[@itemprop="email"]/a')]
        print(mail)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('mail not found')
        mails.append('')**
```

код на странице [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно исправить?

полный код https://pastebin.com/Tkg8egtP

Comment: не нужно весь код без разбора в вопрос помещать, попробуйте минимальный пример создать, который ошибку показывает [mcve]

Comment: @jfs ну и как ты сделаешь воспроизводимый пример на python?

Comment: А у вас mails только в случаи ошибки заполняется

Comment: @Елена, а теперь у вас слишком короткий пример: есть вызов функции `get_links()`, а самой функции нет. Проблема именно в ней. И по ссылке на pastebin этой функции тоже нет.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Tkg8egtP вот полный код и вопрос написала функцию get_links()

Comment: Ответ пока удалил. Настоящая причина - у вас в get_links каждый раз пустой список в links получается.